# Typeahead 0.10.2 does not show suggestions in Rails 4 / Bootstrap 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, typeahead

I'm trying to integrate typeahead 0.10.2 in my Rails 4 app, but no suggestions show up when entering something into the text field. I started with the most basic example, which fails already.

### Javascript

I've downloaded the bundled js file and placed it under `vendor/assets/javascripts/typeahead_lib.js` ([File](https://github.com/nTraum/tf2movies/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/typeahead_lib.js) on GitHub).

The jQuery plugin is called in `app/assets/javascripts/typeahead.js` ([File](https://github.com/nTraum/tf2movies/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/typeahead.js) on GitHub) and looks like this:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
        matches.push({ value: str });
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#search').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

Both files are included in the assets pipeline, here's the manifest ([File](https://github.com/nTraum/tf2movies/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js) on GitHub):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require typeahead_lib
//= require typeahead
//= require rails-timeago
//= require fitvid_lib
//= require fitvid
//= require mixitup_lib
//= require mixitup
//= require slick_lib
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require cocoon
```

### HTML

The text field is located in Bootstrap's navbar([File](https://github.com/nTraum/tf2movies/blob/master/app/views/shared/_navbar.html.slim) on GitHub), the Slim file looks like this:

```
= form_tag('/search', :class => 'navbar-form navbar-left') do
  .form-group
    = label_tag('search', nil, :class => 'sr-only')
    = text_field_tag(:query, nil, :size => 17, :placeholder => 'Search', :class => 'form-control typeahead', :id => 'search')
```

which translates to the following HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="us7C8pezJJkB+09kN3irL37o+hbUUfjd2EP+SFm0hc8=">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
    <input class="form-control typeahead" id="search" name="query" placeholder="Search" size="17" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

### Live example

You can check the whole site on [tf2movies.org](http://tf2movies.org), where the (non functional) search bar can be found. I don't have any idea how to debug this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your typeahead.js jQuery plugin is actually being run.

Make sure your plugin code resides within a jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    ...
}
```

(Obviously replace the ellipsis with the rest of your code!)

Also ensure that your webpage is correctly referencing this script.